# Is passing setState from parent to child an antipattern

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a componenet with a lot of properties in its state, most of them should be updated by child component. Passing `this.setState` from parent to child would be convinient as i wouldn't have to handle updating each property individually. However this also feels like an react antipattern. Is passing `this.setState` a good idea or what is a proper way to deal with this situation ?

EDIT: After seeing first answers I see that I haven't stated the problem correctly. I will make it more clear on example. I'm using typescript BTW.

```
class Parent extends React.Component<Props, State> {
    state: State = {
        prop1: "something",
        prop2: "something",
        prop3: "something",
        ...
        propn: "something",
        ...
    }

    render() {
        return (
              <div>
                    <Child handleChange={this.setState} /> //version 1 - universal
                    <Child //version2 - every prop has its own handler
                          handleChange1={(prop1) => {this.setState({prop1: prop1})}
                          handleChange2={(prop2) => {this.setState({prop2: prop2})}
                          ...
                          handleChangen={(propn) => {this.setState({propn: propn})}
                    />
              </div>
        );
    }

}
```

I know handler should have own methods and not be declared here as an arrow function, but this is just for demonstration purposes. So Version 1 looks way simpler but it seems that passing `this.setState` is not the way it's meant to be. Is it ok to use it as here ?

Comment: Don't know why you think it's an antipattern when it's in the [official tutorial](https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html#lifting-state-up).

Comment: @JaredSmith Tutorial doesn't even mention that!

Comment: Did you read the code in the link? It passes a function that calls setState to a child component, and that's the official React tutorial.

Comment: @JaredSmith Yes. Did you read my question ? I don't ask if we can pass handling method to child. I know we can do this. I ask about passing `this.setState` directly (as you see in example, version 1). Even though it makes things easier I have never seen anyone do this, that's why it seems suspicious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's a common need to children update Parent's state. At parent you set a function like `handleState`, pass down to children which in certain conditions invokes it.

This function will hold logic to call `this.setState`, and most likely receives params to update parent state.

Comment: So you would suggest writing n functions to handle n state properties ?

Comment: you dont write n function for n states. just pass an object as param to the function. could be something like: `handleState(newState) { this.setState(newState) }`

Comment: Well the function you wrote is basically unnecessary copy of `this.setState`  so this is `version 1` from my example. However if you don't see any problem with it, that answers my question. Thank you!